# GWT Resizable Composite

Tags: gwt, resize, composite

I'm trying a simple experiment with `ResizableComposite` by logging width & height of the widget, but I'm not getting any response.

**ResizableFlowPanel**

```
public class ResizableFlowPanel extends FlowPanel implements RequiresResize, ProvidesResize {

    public ResizableFlowPanel() {
    super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResize() {
    GWT.log(this.getOffsetHeight() +","+this.getOffsetWidth());
    }

}
```

**AppBody.java**

```
public class AppBody extends ResizeComposite implements RequiresResize,
    ProvidesResize {
    private static AppBodyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(AppBodyUiBinder.class);

    public AppBody() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResize() {
    GWT.log(this.getOffsetHeight() + "," + this.getOffsetWidth());
    super.onResize();
    }

    interface AppBodyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, AppBody> {
    }

}
```

**AppBody.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder ...>
    <e:ResizableFlowPanel styleName="{bundle.appBodyStyle.app_body}">

    </e:ResizableFlowPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

When I resize the browser, I'm not getting any log messages.

Comment: FlowPanel does resize according to its parent. I do not think you need to write "ResizableFlowPanel extends FlowPanel implements RequiresResize"

Comment: `RequiresResize` will only make a difference if you add the widget to a parent that implements `ProvidesResize` - so what are you adding AppBody to? And why isn't AppBody fulfilling `ProvidesResize` and invoking `onResize()` on any child that implements `RequresResize` (a.k.a. the `ResizableFlowPanel`)?

Comment: Colin, I'm adding it to a HtmlPanel; so that's probably why it is not working.  Is there a way I can track the size of a panel without having everything from RootPanel onwards implementing the two interfaces?